# Map two columns of a dataframe, based on their group/id, in increasing order of the closer values, in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, sorting, group-by, mapping

I have a datafame as such:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create data_set
data_set = {'id': [1,
                   1,
                   1, 
                   1,
                   1,

                   2,
                   2,
                   2, 
                   2,
                   2,

                   3,
                   3,
                   3, 
                   3,
                   3,

                   ],
            'Salary': [16,
                       16,
                       16, 
                       16,
                       16,

                       42,
                       42,
                       42, 
                       42,
                       42,

                       28,
                       28,
                       28, 
                       28,
                       28,
                       ],
            'Reference_id': [1,
                             2,
                             3, 
                             4,
                             5,

                             1,
                             2,
                             3, 
                             4,
                             5,

                             1,
                             2,
                             3, 
                             4,
                             5,
                             ],

            'Reference_Salary': [10,
                                 20,
                                 30, 
                                 40,
                                 50,

                                 10,
                                 20,
                                 30, 
                                 40,
                                 50,

                                 10,
                                 20,
                                 30, 
                                 40,
                                 50,
                                 ],
             'Expenditure': [100,
                             210,
                             320,
                             430,
                             540,

                             90,
                             200,
                             310,
                             420,
                             530,

                             80,
                             190,
                             300,
                             410,
                             520,
                             ],
            
               'Leaves': [ 17.5,
                           45. ,
                           72.5,
                           100. ,
                           127.5,

                           7.5,
                           35. ,
                           62.5,
                           90. ,
                          117.5,

                           2.5,
                           25. ,
                           52.5,
                           80. ,
                           107.5,
                           ],
               }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data_set)
print("\n df = \n",df)
```

The data frame looks as such:

[image]

Here, 'Salary=16' with 'id=1' appears 5 times and needs to be compared with 'Reference_Salary = 10 to 50' which is marked by its corresponding 'Reference_id = 1 to 5'.

The Salary difference and hence the entire row, should appear from minimum to maximum.

The same logic follows for other id's of df.

I wish to see the result in a dataframe as such:

[image]

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `np.abs()`:

```py
df['tmp'] = np.abs(df['Salary'] - df['Reference_Salary'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'tmp'])
df.pop('tmp')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    id  Salary  Reference_id  Reference_Salary  Expenditure  Leaves
1    1      16             2                20          210    45.0
0    1      16             1                10          100    17.5
2    1      16             3                30          320    72.5
3    1      16             4                40          430   100.0
4    1      16             5                50          540   127.5
8    2      42             4                40          420    90.0
9    2      42             5                50          530   117.5
7    2      42             3                30          310    62.5
6    2      42             2                20          200    35.0
5    2      42             1                10           90     7.5
12   3      28             3                30          300    52.5
11   3      28             2                20          190    25.0
13   3      28             4                40          410    80.0
10   3      28             1                10           80     2.5
14   3      28             5                50          520   107.5
```